# Regex with positive look ahead that excludes certain strings (using find in vscode)

Tags: regex, text, visual-studio-code, regex-lookarounds

I'm using the regular expression option within `find` in vscode on a large .txt file. `\w+(?=\s?Books)` finds every word that occurs directly before the the word `Books` in the document.

But this regex returns too many results. I'd like to exclude from the results any occurrences of `QuickBooks` or `Google Books`, as well as other strings.

How do I do exclude certain strings from the results?

`^/(?!Google|Quick)\w+(?=\s?books)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `\b(?!Google|Quick)\w+(?=\s?books)`

Comment: Is the comments section intended for answers to be posted?